# Passing user defined two dimensional array to another function

Tags: arrays, function, multidimensional-array

I am trying to pass a user defined two dimensional array from main to another function, but I am getting lot of errors. Help!
The error occurs while calling function. Please tell me what arguments should be specified while declaring, calling, and defining a user defined function.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int transpose(int a[][int], int, int); //user-defined function
int main()
{
    int size;
    cout << "\nEnter the size of the matrix : "; //entering size of the 
    array
    cin >> size;
    int orignal[size][size]; //declaration of array
    cout << "\nEnter the elements in the array : "; //entering elements in 
    array
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            cin >> orignal[i][j];
        }
    }
    cout << "\nThe elements in the array are :\n"; //displaying elements in 
    array
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            cout << orignal[i][j] << "  ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    transpose(orignal, size, size); //calling user defined function
    return 0; 
}

int transpose(int a[][int column], int row, column)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < column; j++)
        {
            cout << a[i][j] << "  ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

It can be simple done as

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int size;
cout<<"Enter size of Array :\n";
cin>>size;
int a[size][size],b[size][size];
cout<<"\nInput Matrix-A\n";
for(int i=0;i<size;++i)
{
for(j=0;pj<size;j++)
cin>>a[i][j];
cout<<endl;
}
cout<<"\nThe elements in Matrix A is :\n";
for(i=0;i<size;++i)
{
for(j=0;j<size;++j)
cout<<a[i][j];
cout<<endl;
}
for(i=0;i<size;++i)
{
for(j=0;j<size;j++)
b[i][j]=a[j][i];
}
cout<<"\nTranspose of Matrix is:\n";
for(i=0;i<size;++i)
{
for(j=0;j<size;++j)
cout<<" "<<b[i][j];
cout<<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

For passing array to a function,
First Way :

> The receiving parameter of the array may itself be declared as an array.

```
int main()
{
int age[10];
.
.
.
display(age);
return 0;
}
void display(int a[10])
{
}
```

Second Way :

> The receiving parameters may be declared as an unsized array.For single >dimensional array ,size is not neccessary,but while in multi dimensional array,
>   First dimension's size is not neccessary but other'size is neccessary.

```
.
.
//Calling function remain same
.
.
void display(int a[])
{
........
}
```

Third Way:

> The receiving parameter can be declared as a pointer

```
.
.
.
void display(int *a)
{ .....}
```

Input of data to Multi Dimensional array is always encouraged to do inside the function if you don't know the size. In your case just get input inside function or pre define the size of array in your coding

Best is to declare array in global scope ,so that is accesible by both main and user defined function.

Comment: I knew transpose of matrix could be easily obtained in main function, I wanted to pass it to another function only to increase my programming skills and get used to it. I appreciate your efforts you took for me :)

Comment: Its ok,But i also mentioned the conditions in end of the answer. If you want to pass multidimensional array you **MUST KNOW THE SIZE**. You may also use  pointers while passing array.

Comment: I will surely try the techniques you suggested and if I get stuck I'll again ask you to guide me :)

Comment: Why is it so that while passing a multidimensional array to another function, the prototype of that function should be void and not int? 
I tried the techniques you suggested on a user defined array of prototype void and it worked correctly, but when I use those techniques for int prototype I get error!

Comment: Very sorry, it works fine now. I have only one doubt. Suppose I have initialised an array named matrix of 3*3 dimensions and a user defined function another_matrix(int *q, int, int);
From main function when I call the user defined matrix like this " another_matrix(matrix, 3, 3); " it gives me error, but when I call it in this way " another_matrix(&matrix[0][0], 3, 3); " it works fine. Why so? Because both "matrix" and "&matrix[0][0]" points to the base address, then why only one of them works correctly?